# failed to leave a valid exports object in titanium 9.0.1

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-sdk

I have added screenshot which i am getting error while building app for titanium

SDK : 9.0.1

For SDK 8.3.1 and 7.4.2 this error not coming app is working fine for this SDK version only having issue for 9.0.1

```
// requires:
// Set up device detector
var DeviceDetectClass = require('DeviceDetect');
var deviceDetect = new DeviceDetectClass();
```

this we importing in `app.js`
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is `DeviceDetect`?

Comment: one extra js which having code for device size detecting.

Comment: are you trying to access a global function? That changed in 9.x

Comment: yes. mostly in description i mention how we declare.

Comment: any help in this @miga

Comment: where does `checkNetworkStatus()` come from? That function is not mentioned. As for the global functions: just require the file where you use it or use `globals.functionName = function() {}` in app.js. Things in app.js are not global automatically (and shouldn't be!)

Comment: Inside app.js but at bottom it has like it calling at line no 155 and then definition at line no 300

Comment: Devicedetect work in app.js it throw error in other like UI.js other js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit global functions do no longer work in Titanium 9.0.0.GA or higher. Best way to fix this is put those functions in a standalone JS file, and require them in at the place you want to use them.

So `secondfile.js`

```
function checkNetworkStatus() {

}

module.exports = {
  checkNetworkStatus: checkNetworkStatus
}
```

Elsewhere in your app:

```
require('secondfile').checkNetworkStatus();
```

Another way is to put global functions like this in `app.js`. This is however not the recommended way.

```
global.checkNetworkStatus = functon() {}
```

Elsewhere in your app

```
checkNetworkStatus();
```

Comment: probably the same problem, you're trying to access it in a file that doesn't have it

Comment: Starting SDK 9 there are no explicit globals anymore. If you want to make something global you have to do it manually, or use the recommended approach

Comment: Can i get reference documents or link because I want to go deeper in this. Thanks. I will try this but using this need to change all places wherever occurrence.

Comment: first approach works perfect. what about other issue like `deviceDetect` can't find variable ?

Comment: use the same solution for variables, or use `global.` notation. The change was first introduced in [this guide](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Titanium+SDK+7.5.0+Functionality+Update)

Comment: Thanks its works superb. Upvote on question if you feel it was right question. Accepted answer @rene-pot